# Independent variable vs. Uncorrelated variable confusion. How do I interpret this?

Tags: probability-distributions, correlation, time-series

I'm reading *[Time Series Analysis and Forecasting by Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470540648)* by Søren Bisgaard and Murat Kulahci and I'm having trouble conceptualizing a particular passage and it's bugging me enough that I can't move on. The passage is discussing the difference between the independence of two variables and their correlation.

---

[image: my question]

---

My confusion comes in the last paragraph. I'm failing to understand both why those two integrals are equal to `E(XY)` and why that implies `E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)`. Where did the squared terms on the x's come from? Why are we subtracting the integrals? These are all questions that my puny math-jargon-dumb brain is short circuiting on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_X$ is the density function of $X$, then the density of $Y=|X|$ is $f_Y(x)=2f_X(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f_Y(x)=0$ for $x<0$. Thus
$$\tag1E[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Y(x)\,\mathrm dx = 2\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
This intermediate result is not really needed, except that we may be more compfortable with the computation if this $E[Y]$ is finite. 
In fact, we better pick our $X$ and $f$ so that all relevant integrals in these computations exist. A straightforward *explicit* example would be to let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.
What is more important than $(1)$ is the observation that $E[X]=0$ by mere symmetry of $X$: The probability that $a<X<a+\epsilon$ is the same as the probability that $-a-\epsilon<X<-a$, hence everything cancels ; or to see it a different way: We know that $E[cX]=cE[X]$ and as $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$ we conclude $E[X]=E[-X]=-E[X]$, so $E[X]=0$ (if the integral exists). Now notie that $XY$ also has a symmetic distribution: If $a\ge0$ then $a<XY<a+\epsilon\iff \sqrt a<X<\sqrt{a+\epsilon}$ and $-a-\epsilon<XY<a\iff -\sqrt{a+\epsilon}<X<-\sqrt a$; by symmetry of $X$ these probabilities are equal. So by symmetry we also have $E[XY]=0$, hence
$$E[XY] = 0 = 0\cdot E[Y]=E[X]E[Y].$$

---

To answer your explicit question about the $x^2$ in the integrals shown, note that for any suitable function $g$ we can compute the expected value of the random variable $g(X)$ via
$$ E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Since we can compute $Y$ from $X$ via $x\mapsto |x|$, we can compute $XY$ via $g(x)=x\left|x\right|=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{if $x\ge0$}\\-x^2&\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$. Hence
$$ E[XY]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^0(-x^2)f_X(x)\mathrm dx+\int_0^\infty x^2f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
After taking into account the symmetry of $f_X$ (and using the existence of all integrals we encounter) this cancels and (again) shows $E[XY]=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I think you've cleared up my confusion and I can now continue reading without that nagging feeling in my brain that I'm missing something.